# How do I resurrect essential NPCs in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I was having some problems in Whiterun with the guard because I needed to pay a fine of over 3000 gold (a considerable quantity for someone that just started the game), so I decided to kill all the guards. The problem came when [Commander Caius](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Commander_Caius) (an essential NPC) started to attack me, so I attacked him too.

As essential NPCs cannot die, I decided to used the console to set him to be mortal. After that I killed him.

Some of my friends told me that this Caius is an important character in the game, so I want to resurrect him. I still have his corpse, if it's needed.

**Is there any console command that can be used to resurrect someone?**

Thanks.

Comment: You might like to look at [this list of console commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) to get an idea of what's possible beyond the simple `resurrect` mentioned in the answers. I'd advise making the character essential again, to prevent accidental deaths. Most immortal characters are immortal because they have some important role in the quests.

Comment: @SadlyNot I'm a mage.

Comment: If you are going to cheat your way around, why you just didn't add the gold to your character in the first place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just open up the console.  Click on his corpse (you should see his ref id show up as a text string) and enter the command `resurrect`

Comment: I know this is 4 years too late, but what do `resurrect 1` or `resurrect 4` do? I mean the numbers after the command.

Comment: @Lore Friendly AFAIK the optional `resurrect` parameter will also restore all the default items the NPC is supposed to be carrying.   People often use this option to farm high-value items from NPCs.  I've usually seen this value set to 1.  If other values are allowed I'm not sure what they do, but it's a common programming trick to interpret any nonzero value as meaning 'true' i.e. 'this optional value is hereby specified'.